# Find the cell which returns lowest difference from a range in excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I have a set of range of values in a column:

```
Column1 
1.  1       
2.  5
3. 66
4. 23
```

Value to test difference from 20
Value returned 23

Now I want a code that could return the cell value which has the minimum absolute difference from a given number in another cell(say if it contains 20, it should return 23 as 20-1=19,20-5=15,66-20=26 and 23-20=3).

Answer (score 0):

If your set is located in `A1:A4`, and the tested value (20) is in `B1`, following array formula (confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) will return nearest element of the set:

```
 =INDEX(A1:A4,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A4-B1)),ABS(A1:A4-B1),0))
```